# how to center the top links around a figure in hugo

Tags: html, css, hugo

I am getting into hugo, but am not sure how to go about creating a hugo site with tabs that are around a central image. As follows:

[image]

What i can not figure out is (1) how to draw the lines around the headings, (2) more importantly place the image in the center. I have been trying to do this with the academic, and blogophonic and also minimal templates. All the templates that i am trying to look at have the icon in the side.
Perhaps some other template is better but I can't tell how to get the top menu list to center around the round circle (it is a png) in the center. Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Hello. Just normal HTML And CSS... I mean - edit the theme or make your own...

Comment: Thanks! I can write normal HTML and CSS. I am trying to move to Hugo, so I am trying to see how to move the html script to a hugo "format"  but how do i center the icon from the left to the center? Any example? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, no problem, so Hugo just compiles HTML templates. So find the template that is used for whatever icon you are talking about, and add the CSS to center it. Really, that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this HTML in your layout:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And add the following CSS:

```
#navbar {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
#navbar ul {display: flex;}
#navbar ul li {list-style: none;}
#navbar > a {position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);}
```